# Javascript date issue toJSON()

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this:

```
var test = new Date(2019, 03, 15, 13, 15, 0);

 console.log(test); //outputs Mon Apr 15 2019 13:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

 console.log(test.toJSON()); //outputs wrong time 2019-04-15T07:45:00.000Z
```

How do I fix `toJSON()` such that it does not change my time and instead outputs `2019-04-15T13:15:00.000Z`?

Comment: What is the browser you using as it works fine in chrome

Comment: Chrome and I have a cookie in my browser _culture and it's value is en-gb. I suspect it is taking this cookie into consideration while doing toJSON but I don't want it to take the culture into consideration.

Comment: The output is correct in both cases. `toJSON()` uses UTC time, whereas `toString()` (used in the first example) includes the timezone in its output.

Comment: The time is correct (and the same), only the time zone is different. You cannot change the time zone of the string `toJSON` produces. `toJSON` calls `toISOString` which always returns the time in UTC . https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring .

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, what is the alternative way to get 2019-04-15T13:15:00.000Z as output?

Comment: If you feed it back into the program you should get the same behavior as if you inputted in a UTC time.

Comment: @Mrug the `Z` in that string represents the UTC timezone, so that output would be just wrong.

Comment: See [Use JavaScript to convert a date string with timezone to a date object in local time](/questions/11770367)

Comment: @Sirko: It is fine but I need the same time as in Date object

Comment: So you actually want a date representing 13:15 in UTC, not IST?

Comment: Yes, right. I need 2019-04-15T13:15:00.000Z

Comment: Then create the date object in UTC to begin with: `new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 03, 15, 13, 15, 0))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, `toJSON` returns the time in UTC, whereas `new Date` as you call it uses the local time zone.

If you want to create the date object in UTC (i.e. 13:15 UTC), then use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```js
var test = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 03, 15, 13, 15, 0));
console.log(test.toJSON());
```

Dealing with time and time zones can be tricky, which is why usally all timestamps should be stored as UTC and converted to the local time zone (or other time zones) as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`date.toJSON()` prints the UTC-Date into a string formatted as json-date.
And you are printing in IST (GMT+530)
You can offset the time zone using [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

```js
var date = new Date(2019, 03, 15, 13, 15, 0);
console.log(date.toString())

// offsetting the time zone

console.log( new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toJSON());
```

> Edit -getTimezoneOffset() returns the offset in minutes. You have to
>   convert this value into seconds [ 60,000 (milliseconds in a minute) ]
>   and adjust this to the timestamp of your date to get the date you want.